# Can't signing a Message using sha512 in python at iconomi

Tags: python, api, authentication, sha512

I am trying to send an authentificated message over an API at [iconomi.com](https://www.iconomi.com/register?ref=3djw1).
I am used to sign message when dealing with other exchange API, but can't be authentificated with this specific one.

I read the [official documentation](https://iconomi-ag.github.io/iconomi-api/#section/Introduction/Authentication) for authentification:

> You generate the ICN-SIGN header by creating a sha512 HMAC using the
> base64-decoded secret key on the prehash string timestamp + method +
> requestPath + body (where + represents string concatenation) and
> base64-encode the output, where:
>
> the timestamp value is the same as the ICN-TIMESTAMP header. the body
> is the request body string or omitted if there is no request body
> (typically for GET requests). method must always be in upper case

> Example: base64_encode(HMAC_SHA512(secret_key, timestamp + upper_case(method) + requestPath + body))

I found also a java client example on the [official github](https://github.com/iconomi-ag/iconomi-java), please see bellow signature generation in java :

```
private String generateServerDigest(String method, String uri, long timestamp, String body) {
    //return timestamp + request.getMethodValue() + uri + body;
    String checkDigestString = timestamp + method + uri + body;//  "GET+/v1/daa-list+123123123"; //timestamp in epoch milliseconds

    // hash server composited digest with algorithm and apikeys secret
    SecretKeySpec signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(apiSecret.getBytes(), "HmacSHA512");
    Mac mac;
    try {
        mac = Mac.getInstance(signingKey.getAlgorithm());
        mac.init(signingKey);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException e) {
        log.warn("Could not ={}", signingKey.getAlgorithm());
        return null;
    }

    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(mac.doFinal(checkDigestString.getBytes()));
}
```

*Please note that checkDigestString code `timestamp + method + uri + body` and comment `GET+/v1/daa-list+123123123` are already different on the official doc.*

---

And this is my python implementation attempt :

```
def sign(timestamp,method,requestPath,body):
    global api_secret
    base64_decoded_secret_key = base64.b64decode(api_secret)
    content_to_hash = (str(timestamp) + method.upper() + requestPath + body).encode('utf-8')
    sign_digest = hmac.new(base64_decoded_secret_key, content_to_hash , hashlib.sha512).digest()    
    return base64.b64encode(sign_digest).decode('utf-8')
```

When I try this signature method with `requestPath = "/v1/user/balance"` (which required to be authentificated), it fail without error...

---

Does any one used with both java and python may help me to convert this signature method to python ?

Comment: were you able to perform a POST ? GET works for me but POST returns 401 unauthorized for some reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will work for GET:

```
import time,requests
import hashlib,hmac,base64

api_key = "my api key"
api_secret = "my api secret"

defaut_encoding = "utf8"

uri = "https://api.iconomi.com"
requestPath = "/v1/user/balance"
api_url_target = uri+requestPath # https://api.iconomi.com/v1/user/balance
method="GET"
body=""
icn_timestamp = int(1000.*time.time())

message = (str(icn_timestamp) + method.upper() + requestPath + body).encode(defaut_encoding)
signature_digest = hmac.new(api_secret.encode(defaut_encoding), message, hashlib.sha512).digest() #here digest is byte
b64_signature_digest= base64.b64encode(signature_digest).decode(defaut_encoding)

headers_sign= {
    "ICN-API-KEY":api_key,
    "ICN-SIGN":b64_signature_digest,
    "ICN-TIMESTAMP":str(icn_timestamp)
}

s=requests.session()
res = s.get(api_url_target,headers=headers_sign,timeout=3, verify=True).content
print (res)
```

Update for @Karl comment, this code will work for POST:

```
import time,requests
import hashlib,hmac,base64,json

api_key = "my api key"
api_secret = "my api secret"
ticker = "my ticker strategy"


defaut_encoding = "utf8"

uri = "https://api.iconomi.com"
requestPath = "/v1/strategies/"+ticker+"/structure"
api_url_target = uri+requestPath # https://api.iconomi.com/v1/strategies/{my ticker strategy}/structure
method="POST"
body="{'ticker': ticker, 'values': [{'rebalancedWeight': 1., 'targetWeight':1., 'assetTicker': 'XMR', 'assetName': 'Monero', 'assetCategory': 'Privacy'}]}"
icn_timestamp = int(1000.*time.time())

message = (str(icn_timestamp) + method.upper() + requestPath + body).encode(defaut_encoding)
signature_digest = hmac.new(api_secret.encode(defaut_encoding), message, hashlib.sha512).digest() #here digest is byte
b64_signature_digest= base64.b64encode(signature_digest).decode(defaut_encoding)

headers_sign= {
    "ICN-API-KEY":api_key,
    "ICN-SIGN":b64_signature_digest,
    "ICN-TIMESTAMP":str(icn_timestamp)
}

s=requests.session()
res = s.post(api_url_target,headers=headers_sign,json = json.loads(body), timeout=3, verify=True).content
print (res)
```

Comment: Shouldn't this work too for post/updates ? I'm trying to update my structure but get this error b'{"timestamp":1617618493409,"path":"/v1/strategies/PRINCIPLES/structure","status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"","requestId":"031154a9-10370867"}'

Comment: No it should not work like this for POST requests, plz let me sometime to double check how to deal with that ! Regards

Comment: @ASTEFANI nice, I was looking for a python Iconomi script, that actually works. The default pageSize is 25 - I could not get it run to retrieve all my historic activities ("/v1/user/activity"). Do you have an idea?

Comment: @schluk5 good, you may do something like :  s.get(api_url_target,param={"pageNumber":2}, headers=headers_sign,timeout=3, verify=True).content, then Increase the pageNumber until you get an empty transact. list.